# Android Compile time error on switching to Kotlin 1.4 when using LiveData with Coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

Consider a simple Coroutine with LiveData

```
liveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
  emitSource(repo.fetchUser().map { user ->
     // .. Do something 
  }
}
```

Previously till org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:**1.3.72**, this statement was fine.
Now it gives an error

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
         Unit
Found:
         DisposableHandle
```

If you see the `liveData` function in the `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0` library,

```
fun <T> liveData(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    timeoutInMs: Long = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
    @BuilderInference block: suspend LiveDataScope<T>.() -> Unit
): LiveData<T> = CoroutineLiveData(context, timeoutInMs, block)
```

The "block" returns "Unit" which is fine. However, `emitSource` returns `DisposableHandle`.
Now before Kotlin 1.4, the compiler didn't complain. Now suddenly my entire source code is riddled with these errors

Is it because of this new functional interface feature in kotlin?
`DisposableHandle` has just 1 method in it. What has changed? Anybody else face this?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. Not sure if it will help but I'm using `ktx` version of `livedata` dependency: `implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0"`